IC-7200 S-meter behaves strangely - why?
I have Icom IC-7200 and can't get it to work properly. It works fine for TX and RX on FT-8 on 20 m, but when I try to use it the old fashioned way in SSB, I got some strange behavior:

S-meter shows same ridiculously high(9..9+10) reading at quiet place between stations and at loud stations
When I adjust RF gain to more, my S-meter shows less points

Reception is fine though. When I connect my G-90 to the same cable - I have S2-3 noise level, S9-9+ on loud stations, and similar reception, so probably my noise levels and antenna are fine.
Is this a normal behavior for 7200? Am I missing some crucial setting? Or is my TRX just broken?

I am interested to know if anyone has used an external automatic tuner with IC-7200?
My 7200 doesn't tune at all .

@RuvenPrasadOscar Hello!  It's pretty unlikely someone will respond to you in a comment on another question... you should really post this as a new question.
Also, you will notice I migrated this to be a comment. Please don't use answers to make comments. :) I realize that as a new user you cannot yet add comments. :) :) New question is the way to go!

Yes, that's normal behavior. When you turn the RF gain down, you're reducing te receiver's sensitivity, which means the lowest signal level it can detect goes up — and the lowest meter reading you see goes up accordingly. If it sits at S9 in a "quiet spot", that means that stations below S9 will be attenuated enough to be basically inaudible.
